# How to replace a character display only for the `italic` face?

Tags: font-lock, display, unicode

I am using a font that does not include italic characters. However, it does include characters like `mathematical italic small a`, which I would like to use instead.

I can set up a display-table that maps a regular character `a` to its mathematical italic counterpart .

```
(let ((d (make-display-table)))
  (aset d ?a (vector ?))
  (set-window-display-table nil d))
```

But I can't figure out how to use this display-table *only for italic text*.